# Emitting an event in Node.js

Tags: node.js, events

I have a Library that uses sockets that I'm trying to edit to emit an event, broadly the code looks like this:

```
function Library(port, host) {
  this.myData = [];
  this.socket = net.connect( ... );
  this.socket.on('data', this._ondata.bind(this));
  this.socket.on('error', this._onerror.bind(this));
  this.socket.on('close', this._onclose.bind(this));
}
Library.prototype._ondata = function() {
  //do stuff
  //have the data we want
  this.myData.push(stuff);
  this.socket.end();
}
Library.protoype._onclose = function() {
  console.log('this gets logged');
}
modules.export = Library;
```

I want to emit an event in the `_onclose` method such that I could do something like

```
var lib = new Library(port, host);
lib.on('emitted-event', function() {
  var data = lib.myData;
});
```

because if I just access `lib.myData` straight away it's still an empty array. But I'm struggling to emit an event. What I'm getting at the moment is Library has no method on. So clearly I'm not adding an emitter in the right way. Anyone know what that is?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/nodejs-events-and-eventemitter/

Comment: `this.MyData.push(stuff);` should be `this.myData.push(stuff);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Node's built in events library.

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    util = require('util');

function Library(port, host) {
  (...)
}

Library.protoype._onclose() = function() {
  this.emit('emitted-event');
}

util.inherits(Library, EventEmitter);
```

Then you'd do:

```
var lib = new Library(port, host);
lib.on('emitted-event', function() {
  var data = lib.myData;
});
```

Comment: Ok this is getting more complicated than I though it would. The `this.socket` line is `this.socket = net.connect(port, host, this._onsocketConnected.bind(this));` and adding what you've suggested results in `TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined`. So `Library.prototype._onsocketConnected()` isn't being defined?

Comment: Are you calling your constructor using `new`? Which you need to be doing since prototypes are part of constructors.

Comment: Yes I am, I'm thinking it maybe easier to add a method in the Library itself that returns `this.myData` but only when the socket's closed. Then in I'd do something like `var lib = new Library(...); var data = lib.getData();` Maybe that'd be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Fortune's answer would work.  Howeever:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
var util = require('util')

function Library(port, host){
  var self = this; //probably want to add this.  if you call from any other function you want proper "this"
  EventEmitter.call(this);
  ...
  var myobj = { eaten: [burger, fries] };
  self.emit('blurp', myobj);
}
util.inherits(Library, EventEmitter)
exports = module.exports = Library; // or new Library(); if you want a singleton
```